# How to lock the rotation of a GameObject when using RadialView？

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm using RadialView to keep a GameObject in the user's view. With default settings, RadialView not only moves the object to keep it in the user's view, but at the same time, RadialView will rotate the object to keep the object facing the user.

Now I want the object only to stay in the user's view, but keep its rotation unchanged, I'm wondering how to set RadialView to achieve such goal, or will I have to use another approach?

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out this line of RadialView component, so that it will not reassign the rotation value: [RadialView.cs L232](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/06a06778e38da622b37cc299a93f16e143b7bdeb/Assets/MRTK/SDK/Features/Utilities/Solvers/RadialView.cs#L232)

```
        //GoalRotation = goalRotation;
```